# Shrink stacked images to fit parent's height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I have an HTML page that is using Bootstrap to show a weather forecast. This page is ultimately going to be shown inside of an `iframe`, so it has fixed dimensions. When the width is >= 768px, I want the images to show horizontally. This works fine when you make the browser wider. When the width is <768px, I want the images to stack themselves and shrink so that all of the text and images fit within the dimensions of the `iframe`. This is where I'm having trouble.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/donnapep/ALkKB/11/). I've used a parent `div` with fixed dimensions to simulate the `iframe`, and set its background color to show where the content overflows its parent. What should be showing is the day, followed by the image, followed by the high / low temperature beneath the image. This should then be repeated for Saturday and Sunday. Instead, the content is overflowing its container and being cut off. Also, the text is not showing in the proper order. I want to fix this while still ensuring that the horizontal images don't break when the browser is wider.

Comment: do you want the image to be responsive?

Comment: Yes, the images are what should scale down in order to fit everything.

Comment: i mean when the browser is minimised you want them to stack vertically or just reduce in width to stay 3 in row

Comment: If the browser is <768px, I would like for everything to stack vertically such that the content does not overflow its `iframe`. If the browser is >=768px, the images should be horizontal (this part already works, but I don't want the solution for the above to break it). Hope that helps clear things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate all of your help San. I ended up eliminating the use of Bootstrap and just implemented my own CSS media queries based on the orientation of the `iframe`. I also had to use some Javascript to calculate how much room was left for the images once all of the other data was loaded and displayed.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit confusing for me i guess as I'm still unable to understand your question completely. But is that what you are looking for? 
http://jsfiddle.net/ALkKB/15/

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
#iframe{width:100%; height:auto;}   
}
```